# Uniquely identify users for GCM subscription lists

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to have a couple of "subscription lists" that will distribute different types of notification to users using GCM (as an example, take news categories: general, sports, finance, etc.).

I want users to be able to sign up for these lists (or unsubscribe from them). I can handle this logic at the server-side, by adding/deleting users' registration_ids from subscriptions tables, but how can I uniquely and securely identify them?

I'm looking for something to act as a unique user ID to act as an glue between the server (and the database) and the app at the client-side (the user's registration_id).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution :

First of all, you must have some login process in your app, in which your server would assign some unique identifier to each user of your application. If you want, in addition, to support the same user using your app on multiple devices, your server will also have to assign some unique device identifier for each device on which your app is installed.

Your DB can have to following relationships :

1. user-id to device-ids - a one to many relationship
2. device-id to registration-id/s - this could be either a one to one relationship (if you choose to store only the latest registration id for each device) or a one to many relationshop (if you choose to keep all the registration ids that GCM ever assigned to the device).
3. list-ids to user-ids - a many to many relationship

Your subscription lists can hold user-ids. THis way, when you want to send a message to all users on some list, you'll find for each user all the matching device-ids, and then for each device-id, you'll find the latest registration-id.